# 'shutdown /s' execution failed with error code 1190 on EC2

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2

I have been providing a userdata powershell script to a scheduled EC2. It works well.

I noticed, occasionally, the EC2 wouldn't shutdown after the ~10 minute task it runs (presumably something in the process hangs). So I added a line to the userdata powershell script `shutdown /s /t 1800`, just as a catch all.

But it returns

> 'shutdown /s' execution failed with error code 1190

I am not sure why?

If I run `shutdown /a`, then try again, it still gives the same message.

I am sorry that I do not know if I am doing something wrong in powershell or if the issue is a combination with the EC2 and powershell (it could be either)

Comment: Error 1190 means [ERROR_SHUTDOWN_IS_SCHEDULED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-).  According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiateshutdowna#return-value), you need to over-ride the 'grace period' to shutdown now.  Does it help if you use `shutdown /s /t 0`?

Comment: This question belongs on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).